# Can't get my floated element to sit where I want it to

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm trying to get my image to sit next to an `<H3>`

I floated the `<div>` in which my image sits in (will apply some JavaScript to it later), but for the life of me I cannot get it to have a space of around 10 or 12px next to the H3 that it sits next to.

I can do it if I apply a margin-right of 130px or so, HOWEVER there are some H3 elements that will not be the same length every time. I thought I could get the `<h3>` just have an auto width so it would stop whenever the text would stop (like my `<h5>` and `<h4>` elements seem to be doing.), but it seems to be taking up the whole line. So my problem will appear (as you can see) if I apply the `margin-right:130px` or more because there are subsequent `<h3>` elements that will be longer than "Complexity Factors".

I wonder if I should sit my `<h3>` elements in that section inside of a div perhaps and set dimensions on that div? In any case, here is my CSS (which with positioning, I am kind of shaky with, admittedly)

here is the page in question:

http://scope-stage.scholastic.com/issues/090113/narrative-nonfiction

```
            /******EXPAND AND COLLAPSE BUTTONS******/

       .expandingBtn img { 
      float:right;
      background-image:('expandBtn.png');
      margin-right:115px;
      margin-top:-13px;
      clear:both;
}

and my markup:
              <h3 class="colorScheme">
                Complexity Factors</h3>
            <div class="expandingBtn">
                <img src="/resource/uploads_scope/img/expandBtn.png" /></div>
            <p>
                See how this text will challenge your students.</p>
            <!--THIS SECTION WILL BE HIDDEN UNTIL A THE EXPAND BUTTON IS CLICKED-->
            <div class="hidden">
                <h4>
                    Purpose</h4>
                <p class="times">
                    The article has a clear purpose&mdash;to inform readers about how a brave teenager stood up to the Taliban&mdash;as well as an implicit purpose&mdash;to show how just getting an education is difficult for many young people around the world.</p>
                <h4>
                    Knowledge Demands</h4>
                <p class="times">
                    Comprehension will be aided by knowledge of current world events and geography. The major topics (free speech, the Taliban, terrorism, girls&rsquo; education worldwide, fighting oppression) will be unfamiliar to many students.</p>
                <h4>
                    Language Conventionality and Clarity:</h4>
                <p class="times">
                    <strong>Vocabulary:</strong> Many higher academic vocabulary words (e.g., oppressive, pseudonym, unwittingly)</p>
                <p class="times">
                    <strong>Figurative language:</strong> Includes personification (&ldquo;fear was her constant companion&rdquo;) and metaphor (Malala&rsquo;s voice is likened to a weapon)</p>
                <h4>
                    Structure</h4>
                <p class="times">
                    A nonlinear structure that starts in 2012 then goes back to 2007 and then forward to 2013. Includes narrative and informational passages.</p>
            </div>
            <!--THIS ENDS THE FIRST HIDDEN SECTION-->
```

Comment: It would be a lot clearer if you've attached an image showing the exact problem... Searching the entire site is tiring..

Comment: I provided a link to the exact page, I dont know why you would have to search the entire site.
Here's the page:
http://scope-stage.scholastic.com/issues/090113/narrative-nonfiction
and the lower right hand area where it says "Complexity Factors" "Litereature COnnection" and "Skills and Satndards" with the circles with plus signs that are links. Thanks

Comment: I meant the whole page.

Comment: indeed. But I have provided the link to the page, which would be equal to any image I would attach. Do you have an answer though? I could use some help :-)

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can floated h3 and set margin-right:12px; on it

```
h3 {float:left; margin-right:12px;}
.expandingBtn {float:left;} .expandingBtn img {float:none; margin-right:0;}
```

and add something like `<div class="clear"></div>` after h3 and .expandingBtn

```
.clear {
   clear:both; 
   width:100%;
   line-height:0; 
   font-size:0;}
```

Comment: thanks. I did think about reversing what elements float. I'm going to try that.

Comment: no that doesn't seem to work. The issue seems to be that the <h3> is taking up the entire line, I ascertained this by using the inspect element feature of Chrome and see that the box or the <h3> stretches all the way to the end of the line, preventing me from using margin-left on the .expandingBtn class. Thus I have to use margin-right which is going to be problematic when the <h3> text is a different length than "Complexity Factors"

Comment: If you set float:left; on h3, h3 became an element with display:inline-block; Yes, you are right, if h3 will have many words, the width of h3 can be 100%. You may set max-width on h3, for example h3 {max-width:70%;}

Comment: And one more - rule should apply to .expandingBtn {float:left;}, rule for .expandingBtn img {float:none; margin-right:0;}

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, your problem is solved by adding these stylings:

```
.mainRight h3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
.expandingBtn {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Here's a more specific solution based on our discussion (deleted styles are commented):

```
.mainRight h3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
.expandingBtn {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    /* margin-right: 135px; */
    /* margin-top: -13px; */
    /* clear: both; */
}
```

Comment: ^^yes this is what I want. Thanks I will try and see and do what you did. :-)

Comment: actually this seems to cause some problems with the H3 inside the "Essential Questions" div..I dont know why though. Still investigating

Comment: @Jay It doesn't affect it on my browser... What browser are you using?

Comment: on the page that is http://scope-stage.scholastic.com/issues/090113/Paired-Texts (I had to reset it, but will add those styles, and show you) One sec I'm doing 3 things at once

Comment: wth?!? now it does't "break" the page..before it was causing some havoc. I think that sometimes this ezPublisher CMS does weird things, at times I notice all kinds of odd inserted blank <a href"></a> tags for no reason... I'm going to try to apply these to the rest and see what it does

Comment: here's what it does in this page:
http://scope-stage.scholastic.com/issues/090113/lazy-editor

Comment: I think what I'm going to have to do is create a DIV, set dimensions on it, and then place the h3 inside that DIV, then float the DIV with the expand image inside of that DIV. The problem is that darned H3 taking up the entire line.

Comment: @Jay Don't add HTML elements only for indenting stuff. Further more, please delete some of your previous comments on this conversation. Like `not on that page, but on a different page`. Usually wer'e supposed to speak in the chat but you can't access it yet with your current score. I'll take a loot at your link

Comment: @Jay - You didn't do what my update says. You have to remove margin-right etc. and add the styles I've written.

Comment: I copied the style exactly and pasted it in.

Comment: @Jay: Check again. The page you've sent is still using the old CSS. Also please delete older comments in this discussion

Comment: I thank you guys for the help, but I think I'm just going to have to figure a solution out myself..bad enough I have to figure how to apply javascript to the buttons to hide and close the divs. Again, thanks for help.